# Python asyncore/asynchat and JavaScript Socket.io

Tags: python, sockets, socket.io, asyncore

I am new to Python and I have implemented a small server with asyncore. My question is:

> Is there a way to connect from JavaScript front-end and parse messages similar to socket.io? I would like to send some events from Python and interpret them in a web page.